# Is there a good way to run specflow tests in a new app domain?

Tags: appdomain, specflow

Due to some constraints on our production code, we have some .NET services that need to be run with their own config file.  We've been using app-domains to provide arbitrary config files to these services at test run time.

The problem comes when we try and use SpecFlow for these tests - since each step is called separately and from an overall runner class that we don't have direct access to, pushing test data across app-domain boundaries for every single STEP is pretty messy and results in everything being in all sorts of odd lambdas, plus serializability needs to be considered when most of the time we shouldn't need to care about that in a test code context (internal data objects, that sort of thing).

Does anyone have a method by which SpecFlow can be convinced to run all of its steps in a provided app-domain, or generally just play nicer with the app-domain concept in general?

Would it be possible to write a plugin / test generator that did this, and if so would this be very technically complicated?  I had a look at that sort of extensibility but couldn't find the right place to start to do this, so I may have missed it.

(I'm aware that "Refactor your service so you don't need arbitrary config files" would also solve the underlying problem, but for the purposes of this question please assume I can't do that - I'm interested in whether SpecFlow can be configured to solve this, whether on its own or by extending it.)

Edit: After some more investigation I think this -should- be possible by using a custom unit test generator plugin?  The problem I then have is there's basically zero documentation on that, and not many examples around on the internet.  If you can give me a good example that I can look at to adapt that would go a long way...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the parts 'do not have acces to' as I always find it hard to understand why testing is made harder than needs be. An answer: My use of specflow runs a JSon client to test an Api on a server which than (of course) runs in another .net app domain. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Specflow produces the actual test that is run by MSTest (or other test framework) as autogenerated code.  That test method generally looks like:
  Method(){
     RunStep1(stuff);
     RunStep2(different stuff);
     RunStep3(other stuff);
  }

The level above that method, we do not have easy access to - so we cannot force that method to be run in AppDomain X.  We can make each step individually run in AppDomain X, by doing so inside the RunStep1() method which we essentially write based on the step definition, but then you have to pass data in and out of the app domain, which is my issue.

Comment: Thanks, my question is not directed at the technical implementation of specflow. It is clear you do not have access. My question is on the why of not having access? Who controls the code of the higher level entry than? How come access (to that code) can not be obtained? That is where the problem is? Is there a problem in your organisation?

Comment: I'm having troubles with specflow and appdomains as well. We're using a third party library which has unmanaged code in it which handles appdomains badly, and tends to crash the whole process. If we could avoid using extra appdomains, I think it would work. Did you have any luck solving this problem?

Comment: Not really "solving" it I'm afraid.  We eventually put in the work to refactor everything to run outside of an appdomain, and we actually had to stop using specflow for about half of it and revert back to basic MSTest methods because specflow didn't support what we needed to do without using appdomains like this.